# How to set footer in one section of TableView manually (iOS)?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, footer

I would like to implement some code, which changes footer text in one section of the tableView (in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` method). But how can I do it?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

doesn't fit my requirements (It changes only once, during load of the tableView, but I need to change the footer's text after text in tableView cell is changed.

Answer (score 3):

```
    -(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{


        return 120;

    }



    -(NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        if (section == 0) {
            return @"Things We'll Learn";
        } else {
            return @"Things Already Covered";
        }
    }



- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works only if I use static string as in this example. If I use in if clause such code: NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"There are %d symbols", [[[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:tappedRow] textLabel] text] length]];
        return str;

Comment: return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[firstsectionarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]].like this do for all section and take care about numberofrowsinsection function

Comment: What is the firstSectionArray ?? I doesn't have array for section.

Comment: If I know section and row numbers, how can I get textLabel in this cell ??

Comment: @LIAL     UITableViewCell *myCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//    myCell.textLabel

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement `viewForFooterInSection` and add your `textField` there. Also make that textField a property.
2. When you have finished editing you tableViewCells, implement the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method and assign necessary value to the textField of your footerView.
3. Once your textField is set, use `[tableView reloadData]` to implement the `viewForFooterInSection` again and it should work now.

**Edit:**

If you want to change the title of the Footer section after editing the UITableViewCell,

1. Set a global variable or use `NSUserDefaults` to indicate that `tableViewCell` has been edited.
2. `self.tableView reloadData` right after edit.
3. In the method `titleForFooterInSection` check for that variable (this would mean that tableView has been edited) and set the title accordingly.

Comment: viewFoFooterInSection or titleForFooterInSection ??  Should I add textField as subView of Footer follow your advise ??

Comment: Do you want to change footer title or do you want to change the textField inside a footerView ?

Comment: When my cell's text of TableView changed I would like to show quantity of symbols in footer of this cell

Comment: Do you want to change the title of the footer or embed a textField inside footer view and change it ?

Comment: I did not embed any textField inside footer, I just want to change regular text

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 1)
    {
        // For Lable
        UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 40)] autorelease];
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = view.frame.size.height;
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, view.frame.size.width - 20, 44)];
        label.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
        label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        [label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        label.text = @“Your Text Here…..your Text Here”;

        [view addSubview:label];
        [label release];
        return view;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{  
     if(section == 1)
    {

        return 60.0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: More than 4 years left, do you really think that is actual now ?